How do I create a limited user that can only do SSH port forwarding?
I need to create a user on my server that is restricted to only performing SSH port forwarding. This user should not have any other capabilities, such as reading files or executing commands.
The specific use case is to allow an untrusted server behind a NAT to connect to this limited user and use reverse port forwarding to expose a port.
How can I configure such a user with these restrictions?

For example https://askubuntu.com/a/50000

Basically disable the shell imho
